# How to apply background fade transition on hover in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to apply the fadeIn and fadeOut effect on a background image when you hover over the button. Here is an example of what I would like to do: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/4z2zq/

I tried applying three different ways to apply this technique. I first tried it in CSS by using keyframes, but found this solution to be ineffective due to how the background images are setup.

The second was applying "ease-in" transitions in the .css section in jQuery. However, this doesn't seem to trigger the ease-in transitions.

The third was adding "fadeIn()" and "fadeOut()" using jQuery, but I'm not sure why it's not triggering the fade for the second background image upon hover.  Here is the code I'm working with:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Preload
  $('<img/>').hide().attr('src', 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517164976876-978dd0f4f6fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=e84eb8d852ae0be5f5561be594ca6d46&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80').load(function() {
    $('#main').append($(this));
  });

  $('.button').hover(function() {
    $('#main').css({
      'background-image': 'url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517164976876-978dd0f4f6fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&s=e84eb8d852ae0be5f5561be594ca6d46&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80")',
      'OTransition': 'opacity 2s ease-in',
      'MsTransition': 'opacity 2s ease-in',
      'MozTransition': 'opacity 2s ease-in',
      'WebkitTransition': 'opacity 2s ease-in',
      'transition': 'opacity 2s ease-in'
    });
  }, function() {
    $('#main').css('background', '');
  });
  /*$('.button').hover(function() {
        $('#main').fadeIn(); 
      }, function() { 
      $('#main').fadeOut(); 
  });*/
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  right: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 54px;
  width: 5000px;
}

#background #main {
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
  height: 463px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 1600px auto;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519116678967-5b71031f2c9d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=acf40632c2b8b79e0d902e6f782f06c7&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80');
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: tomato;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 22px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: tomato;
}

.roll-text {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 420ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.roll-text:last-child {
  color: #fff;
}

.rollover:hover .roll-text:first-child {
  margin-top: -38px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="background">
    <div id="main" class="printer">

      <div class="wrap">
        <h1>Hover over button!</h1>
        <a class="button rollover">
          <span class="roll-text">Hover Me</span>
          <span class="roll-text">Let's Go</span>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

from your snippet you need to hover over a button and make the divs toggle their visibility, if so:

```
$('button').hover(function() { 
    $('#div1').fadeIn();
    $('#div2').fadeOut(); 
}, function() { 
    $('#div2').fadeIn();
    $('#div1').fadeOut();
});
```

try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4z2zq/1032/) and LMK